# How to turn of styles of a Magento Theme for just 1 page? (Magento 1.9)

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I want to create a Magento CMS Page from Admin Panel by navigating to CMS -> Pages but when i included bootstrap and added some styles there, page got a weird styling maybe due to the default Magento theme styling and now I want to completely turn of Magento Theme styles for that one single page.

Any ideas on how to do it ??

Answer (score 0):

- You can update Page Layout on the Design tab. You have used XML to remove CSS from default theme:

> ```
> <reference name="head">
>     <!-- For CSS in the skin folder -->
>     <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/YOU_CSS_FROM_CURRENT_THEME.css</name></action>
> </reference>
> ```

- You can change to Empty from Layout field  to check from the Page Layout section
- You can use the Base theme by updating the theme from the "Custom Theme" field in Custom Design section